# How to automatically adjust height of element

Tags: html, css

I have a design consisting of three divs ( http://jsfiddle.net/herrturtur/Mem6u/ ), put next to each other by display: inline-block, but for some reason the last div appears in the middle of the page.

If possible, I'd like to display the three divs next to each other, with the height of the switch div adjusting automatically to the height of the div containing the select element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the function of the switch? you may be able to work this with the float method and strategically placed "clear"..

if you have the option to use JQuery there is a handy tool called accordion (or accordian as there are a couple) that can perform the actions you want relatively easy.. have you already developed the code to perform the actual switch?

**UPDATE:**
I think is is similar to what you are looking to do .. let me know

working url with this code:
http://home.comcast.net/~elkins35/test.html

Just view the source to see the edits to the code you were using

Comment: I eventually want the "first" and "second" div to be displayed next to each other. The first switch will move the whole "container" to the left, and the second switch will move the whole container to the right, so that at any time, only first OR second is displayed.